# Using multiple namespaces in html element

Tags: html, namespaces

Could having multiple namespaces in the html element cause any problems or conflicts? I realize this is a very broad question so I'm not expecting specific pinpoint answers just overall possibilities.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's totally fine. The whole point of supporting namespaces in XML is to allow this sort of usage.